# Documentum application connectors for pdf

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, documentum, emc, webtop

We are exploring if it is possible to integrate Documentum with pdf . Is it possible to have a EMC documentum application connectors for Adobe PDF. ?

Comment: SO is not kind of a site for this kind of questions but I'll answer it anyway

Answer (score 1):

EMC Documentum platform have application connectors as product which is installed on top of the platform. Currently they cover only Microsoft Word, Excel, Outlook and PowerPoint. However you have SDK which you can use to built your own application connectors - which is exactly what you need.

You have documentation available here (EMC support site login reuired):

- [User guide](https://support.emc.com/docu56524_Documentum-Application-Connectors-6.8-User-Guide.pdf)
- [Developer guide](https://www.emc.com/collateral/TechnicalDocument/docu56531.pdf)

Comment: We do have custom application connectors for all Microsoft Office products but the business wants us to explore if it is possible to have a similar customisation for PDF